# How can I get the ios provisioning profile?

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-build

How can I get the ios provisioning profile without ios device? 
How can I build my application here https://build.phonegap.com?

Comment: You don't need an iOS device to get a provisioning profile. But you do have to sign-up for development account.

Comment: You can register for the account rokjarc is talking about here: https://developer.apple.com/register/index.action

Answer (score 0):

You need to register one Apple ID account [here](https://developer.apple.com/register/index.action) and then you can [use OpenSSL](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/detailed_guide_for_setting_up_building_ios_apps_without_a_mac).